# itms-services // action=purchaseIntent not opening the App

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, ios11

On the iOS11 Apple introduced IAP purchases that can be initated from the AppStore. For testing this, in [WWDC17 Whats new in StoreKit video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/303/) they gave the following URL scheme to use:

```
itms-services://?action=purchaseIntent&bundleId=com.example.app&productIdentifier=product_name
```

Now I've tried this several times with both of our Development app (IAP items not in store) and production app (IAP items are in store). Has anyone got this working? Are there some special steps I am missing?

EDIT: It ended up as silly as me typoing the URL. Instead of bunldeId=, I had written bundleID=. So just be super careful as the URL is case-sensitive. Luckily someone else had made the exact same typo and found the solution: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/83709

Answer (score 4):

I had trouble with this as well, the trick to make it work for me is entering the full productIdentifier, like com.company.app.pid. Apple's doc was pretty misleading...

Answer (score 2):

I got it worked by replacing those values (`bunldeId` and `productIdentifier`):

`itms-services://?action=purchaseIntent&bundleId=com.app&productIdentifier=com.app.product.identifier`

- The bundleId (`com.app`) can be found in your Xcode project: In the `.pbxproj` file, look for `General > Bundle Identifier`
- The productIdentifier (`com.app.product.identifier`) can be found in `App store connect > Features > In-App purchases > Product ID`
- Note that the link is case sensitive.